# .NET WEB API throws 500 Internal server error in IIS on POST only

Tags: iis

I am not sure why yet, but POST throws a 500 in IIS (works ok in Visual Studio debug mode).

The PUT works, as does the GET.  So this is a pretty specific problem I have narrowed down quite a bit.

It's just in IIS, not in Visual Studio
GET and PUT work fine, just POST is failing.

And yes, the POST works fine in visual studio, so it's not code.

I am confident this is an IIS configuration issue, or something I need in web.config that isn't there?

Comment: Did you check windows event log?

Comment: Event log shows nothing.

Comment: This has to be a setting in IIS I am missing, since the software works just fine in Visual Studio under debug/IIS Express

Comment: I think i found a clue to the problem.  In IIS the handler mappings don't include POST most of them, while GET, PUT, etc is there.  This does appear to be what's happening as the other operations work just fine.  I just don't know what handler needs changed and there are dozens of them. :\